# Solution of hackerrank Binary Tree Nodes question

Tags: sql, binary-search-tree

You are given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P, where N represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of N.

Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:

Root: If node is root node.
Leaf: If node is leaf node.
Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.
Sample Input

Sample Output

1 Leaf
2 Inner
3 Leaf
5 Root
6 Leaf
8 Inner
9 Leaf

Explanation

The Binary Tree below illustrates the sample:

why below solution is not working :
select n,
CASE when P is null then 'Root'
when (select count(*) from BST where n = p)>0 then 'Inner'
else 'Leaf'
end as nodetype from BST
order by n

and below solution is working:
select n,
CASE when P is null then 'Root'
when (select count(*) from BST where b.n = p)>0 then 'Inner'
else 'Leaf'
end as nodetype from BST b
order by n

Comment: The case statement is constructed incorrectly in the first query.

Answer (score 1):

In your fist query you are comparing `n` with `p` column within the subquery which should never be true.

In second query you are comparing `n` column of outer query with `p` column of subquery which will return more than 0 if there is at least one leaf under the `b.n` node otherwise it will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using a case statement is a way to go. However, to determine if a node is 'Inner' one needs to see if it is a parent to another node i.e. is its value N in the set of all P values.

```
SELECT N, CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN 'Root'
    WHEN N IN (SELECT P FROM BST) THEN 'Inner'
    ELSE 'Leaf' END as node_type FROM BST ORDER BY N
```

Answer (score 0):

By using below code, you can easily solve the binary tree nodes question.In foreach statement we can check the max value and print in console

```
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
    string[] groupings = Convert.ToString(n, 2).Split("0");
    int max = 0;
    foreach(string s in groupings){
        if(max < s.Length){
            max = s.Length;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Here at SO code only answers are **not considered good answers**, though, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).